# Connect AWS - Cyberduck

Tags: amazon-ec2, cyberduck

I am trying to create a connection to my AWS server through my Cyberduck. I created new instance (new key pair, new pemfile). But every time I try to connect it will ask password, which I don't have any. I use my .pem to connect, but have no luck. Been trying for 2 days now. I did the chmod 400, chmod 600. Whenever I checked on my terminal using ssh, it says Permission denied (public key). Any advise? I already googled same issues, but had no luck with their solutions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've created [this](http://youtu.be/hd4oL3WIPVM) tutorial, Just follow the steps, you should be able to connect.

Steps:

Open Cyberduck - > Open Connection -> Select SFTP from drop down Provide necessary parameters and under more options Click "Use public key authentication" and specify your path to .pem file. Then press connect button

Use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9BDvg42-JI) if you use file zilla.

Comment: There is no "Use public key authentication" option in Open Connection anymore

Comment: You can use SSH private Key